# Remove empty spaces inside <p> tags using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, trim

There are some paragraphs in my string html that look like this:

```
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</p>
```

I want to remove empty spaces inside `p` tags and turn it into:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua</p>
```

Notice that a `p` tag like this should leave changed:

```
<p class="has-media media-640"><img alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" height="357" src="http://www.example.com/img/lorem.jpg" width="636"/></p>
```

What I want is:

```
for p in soup.findAll('p'):
    replace p.string with trimmed text
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can replace text with to the [`element.string.replace_with()` method](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring):

```
for p in soup.find_all('p'):
    if p.string:
        p.string.replace_with(p.string.strip())
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''\
... <p>
...     Text with whitespace
... </p>
... <p>No whitespace</p>
... <p><span><img /></span></p>
... ''')
>>> for p in soup.find_all('p'):
...     if p.string:
...         p.string.replace_with(p.string.strip())
... 
u'\n    Text with whitespace\n'
u'No whitespace'
>>> print str(soup)
<html><head></head><body><p>Text with whitespace</p>
<p>No whitespace</p>
<p><span><img/></span></p>
</body></html>
```

This will only strip whitespace *directly contained in the tag*. If you have other tags contained then no stripping takes place.

You can use the [`element.strings` sequence](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings) to handle `<p>` tags with nested tags in them. I'd **not** trim all spaces; leave one space around each string if present:

```
whitespace = u' \t\n\r\x0a'  # extend as needed

for p in soup.find_all('p'):
    for string in list(p.strings):  # copy so we can replace some
        left = string[:1] in whitespace
        right = string[-1:] in whitespace
        if not left and not right:
            continue  # leave be
        new = string
        if left:
            new = ' ' + new.lstrip()
        if right:
            new = new.rstrip() + ' '
        string.replace_with(new)
```

Demo:

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''\
... <p>
...     Text with whitespace
... </p>
... <p>No whitespace</p>
... <p>
...     A nested 
...     <span>tag</span>
...     is not a problem
... </p>
... ''')
>>> whitespace = u' \t\n\r\x0a'  # extend as needed
>>> for p in soup.find_all('p'):
...     for string in list(p.strings):  # copy so we can replace some
...         left = string[:1] in whitespace
...         right = string[-1:] in whitespace
...         if not left and not right:
...             continue  # leave be
...         new = string
...         if left:
...             new = ' ' + new.lstrip()
...         if right:
...             new = new.rstrip() + ' '
...         string.replace_with(new)
... 
u'\n    Text with whitespace\n'
u'\n    A nested \n    '
u'\n    is not a problem\n'
>>> print str(soup)
<html><head></head><body><p> Text with whitespace </p>
<p>No whitespace</p>
<p> A nested <span>tag</span> is not a problem </p>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Thanks. But some p tags were not being changed, for example: `<p>
        I've been revving myself up to switch for a while now, as Chrome has steadily gotten worse and worse. The writing has been on the wall for years. In 2011 Google was already "<a href="http://www.cnet.com/news/google-working-to-reverse-chrome-bloat/#!" target="_blank">aggressively looking at options to bring down the size of Chrome distribution binaries</a>."</p>` It turns out this is not a valid `p.string` object.

Comment: @Desmond: you didn't specify nested strings. Are you sure you want to strip those? The space between `already` and the link object is *significant*.

Comment: No, I didn't want strip any nested strings. I just wanted to remove all spaces before `I've been...` (There was a new line before the actual paragraph starts)